# I've got 100% discount, PayPal and the register button does not show for civiEvent, how do I get it to show?

Tags: civievent, paypal, cividiscount

CiviCRM 5.26.2
Ominpay version of PayPal payments
CiviDiscount

We apply the 100% discount code and the payment form is hidden. There is no register button.

Using the browser inspection tool, there is inline script that always hides the buttons. I can't see this in the CiviCRM source code am unsure where it comes from.

```
CRM.$(function($) {
  $('.crm-submit-buttons', $('#billing-payment-block').closest('form')).hide();
});
```

We suspect that this is a PayPal related feature as the PayPal 'off site' workflow is different.

Comment: The code is from https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Core/BillingBlock.tpl#L205 and i think it is used for all the processors and not just paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we did to get the payment buttons to display when the payment value is $0.

The logic is borrowed from CiviDiscount

CiviDiscount apply button refreshes the page, there are 2 processes

- Person fills out the form and applies the code. The page is refreshed and we check the state to determine whether the register button is shown
- The code is applied before the form is filled out completely. We wait for a form valid state.

The conditions to show the buttons are

- If payment form is hidden
- The value is $0
- A discount code is specified
- The form is valid

In conclusion the following is the code. The *apply discount* button does a page refresh so we can check the value and whether a discount has been applied on page load.There is a watch on this as the inline script that hides the buttons runs after the other scripts. There is also an observer to check whether the form is valid.

```
CRM.$(function ($) {
'use strict';

function interlatedIsTotalZero() {
 var zero = false;
 $('.price-set-option-content input').each(function () {
  var currentTotal = $(this).data('amount').replace(/[^\/\d]/g, '');
  if ($(this).is(':checked') && Number(currentTotal) === 0) {
    zero = true;
  }
 });
 return zero;
}

function interlatedCheckFormValid() {
  var form = $('#billing-payment-block').closest('form');
  return form.valid();
}


// The whole page is reloaded on discount code
function interlatedShowSubmitButtons() {
  // Is the payment form shown?
  var paymentInformation = document.getElementById('payment_information');
  var paymentInformationShown = paymentInformation.style.display;
  var submitButtons = $('.crm-submit-buttons', $('#billing-payment-block').closest('form'));
  if (interlatedCheckFormValid() && paymentInformationShown === 'none' && $('#discountcode').length > 0 && interlatedIsTotalZero()) {
    submitButtons.show();
    return true;
 }

// Form is not valid or similar.
submitButtons.hide();
  return false;
}

// Discount code reloads the whole page. Not a mutation.
interlatedShowSubmitButtons();

// Timing of the jquery to hide the buttons is unpredictable
const buttonsDetectShow = function (mutationsList, observer) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type !== 'attributes') {
      return;
    }
    var buttonsBlockShown = mutation.target.style.display;
    if (buttonsBlockShown === 'none') {
      interlatedShowSubmitButtons();
    }
  }
}

function addObserverIfButtonsAvailable() {
  var buttonsEl = $('.crm-submit-buttons', $('#billing-payment-block').closest('form'))[0];
  if (!buttonsEl) {
    window.setTimeout(addObserverIfButtonsAvailable, 500);
    return;
  }
  interlatedShowSubmitButtons();
  observerButtons.observe(buttonsEl, {attributes: true});
}

const observerButtons = new MutationObserver(buttonsDetectShow);
addObserverIfButtonsAvailable();
var recentMutation = new Date().getTime();

// What happens if we show the button but then the form becomes invalid
const formErrorsDetect = function (mutationsList, observer) {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  if ((now - recentMutation) < 200) {
    return
  }
  recentMutation = now;
  var mutation = mutationsList[0];
  if (mutation.type !== 'childList') {
    return;
  }
  if (mutation.target.classList.contains("error")) {
    // Show or hide the buttons depending on whether the form is valid
    interlatedShowSubmitButtons();
  }
}

function addObserverFormErrors() {
$('.crm-profile .crm-section .content  ', $('#billing-payment-block').closest('form')).each(function () {
  var formEl = $(this)[0];
  observerFormErrors.observe(formEl, {childList: true, subtree: true});
});
}


const observerFormErrors = new MutationObserver(formErrorsDetect);
addObserverFormErrors();

});
```