# Registration button not shown when CiviDiscount results in zero amount to pay

Tags: civievent, cividiscount, stripe

having the same issue as linked below - while using current [stripe](https://docs.civicrm.org/stripe/en/latest/) extension:

[I've got 100% discount, PayPal and the register button does not show for civiEvent, how do I get it to show?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/36072/ive-got-100-discount-paypal-and-the-register-button-does-not-show-for-civieve)

so if using any discount code which results in zero the (reasonable) function to hide the payment processor's button also hides the 'register' button of the form for an event registration and it's not possible to finish it.

does anybody know about a quick way to fix this and/or know where @Interlated could have put that code he posted? (too little reputation to comment there directly)

tia.

Comment: What is your CiviDiscount extension version?

Comment: 3.8.4 on core 5.44.0/wp

Comment: And Stripe extension version?

Comment: been latest/6.6.3 as well - but nevermind - before going to bed i rolled back to an old backup and did the whole system's update process again and now this part of the puzzle is working. thanks for caring.

Comment: Can you pls add as an Answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

was able to resolve this by redoing the whole preceding upgrade process from core 5.2.0 to 5.44.0 directly - 5.2.0 to 5.28.0 which i did couple of weeks ago didn't work flawlessly and seems to have caused this.